# Combine First and Last Names of people based on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, criteria

So I have an interesting scenario.  There are 2 events, for which one of the *Married* **EventType** I'd like to join associated married couples of the house, grouped by an identifier (**HouseID**; 2 people in the same house), the **EventType**, and the **EventDate**. For the case such as an **EventType** of *Birthday*, the 2 residents of the house would not be combined in the same row.  In the case of an **EventType** of *Wedding*, combine the name result of 2 rows (2 rules below based on **LastName**) into 1.  It's possible to have only 1 person for a **HouseID** for the **EventType** of *Wedding* or *Birthday*, so therefore they would list as an individual row.  The combining rules for **EventType** of *Wedding* would be as follows:

1. If the last names are the same, the **FinalName** column result would be **Will and Mary Stanton**
2. If the last names are different, the **FinalName** column result would be **Stephen Jacobs and Janetsy Lilly**.

The combining of the names would be contingent on the **HouseID**, **EventType**, and **EventDate** being the same, specific only to *Wedding*.  This is because it's possible for 2 people to live in a house that are married, but not to each other which we base off the **EventDate**; we assume the **EventDate** is the indicator that they are married to each other.  The example table input is as follows:

```sql
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    HouseID INT,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(64),
    LastName NVARCHAR(64),
    EventType NVARCHAR(64),
    EventDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO @t (HouseID, FirstName, LastName, EventType, EventDate)
VALUES
    (1, 'Will', 'Stanton', 'Birthday', '1974-01-05'),
    (1, 'Mary', 'Stanton', 'Birthday', '1980-05-22'),
    (2, 'Jason', 'Stockmore', 'Birthday', '1987-12-07'),
    (3, 'Mark', 'Mellony', 'Wedding', '2021-04-04'),
    (3, 'Stacy', 'Mellony', 'Wedding', '2021-04-04'),
    (4, 'Stephen', 'Johnson', 'Wedding', '2012-01-30'),
    (4, 'Janetsy', 'Johnson', 'Wedding', '2012-01-30'),
    (5, 'George', 'Jackson', 'Wedding', '2009-11-15'),
    (5, 'Sally', 'Mistmoore', 'Wedding', '2009-11-15'),
    (6, 'Sandy', 'Katz', 'Wedding', '2010-03-19'),
    (6, 'Jeff', 'Trilov', 'Wedding', '2016-09-09'),
    (7, 'Sandra', 'Kirchbaum', 'Wedding', '2011-05-22'),
    (8, 'Jessica', 'Bower', 'Birthday', '1996-02-26'),
    (8, 'Frank', 'Fjorn', 'Birthday', '1969-07-19');
```

The ideal result based on the input table would resemble:

```
| HouseID | FinalName                          | EventType | EventDate  |
| ------- | ---------------------------------- | --------- | ---------- |
| 1       | Mary Stanton                       | Birthday  | 1974-01-05 |
| 1       | Will Stanton                       | Birthday  | 1980-05-22 |
| 2       | Jason Stockmore                    | Birthday  | 1987-12-07 |
| 3       | Mark and Stacy Mellony             | Wedding   | 2021-04-04 |
| 4       | Stephen and Janetsy Johnson        | Wedding   | 2012-01-30 |
| 5       | George Jackson and Sally Mistmoore | Wedding   | 2009-11-15 |
| 6       | Sandy Katz                         | Wedding   | 2010-03-19 |
| 6       | Jeff Trilov                        | Wedding   | 2016-09-09 |
| 7       | Sandra Kirchbaum                   | Wedding   | 2011-05-22 |
| 8       | Jessica Bower                      | Birthday  | 1996-02-26 |
| 8       | Frank Fjorn                        | Birthday  | 1969-07-19 |
```

I have tried a couple of approaches; one of which is using an update statement to update the First Name and update a subsequent FirstName based on Row number using a previously set @Values variable, unioning the result of the types that do not combine (in this case, *Birthday*).  Here is where I built the names then used the MAX() aggregation to select the larger result:

```sql
SELECT HouseID,
       FirstName
     , LastName
     , EventType
     , EventDate
     , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LastName, EventType ORDER BY 1/0)
     , Values1 = CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(MAX))
INTO #EntityValues1
FROM @t
WHERE EventType = 'Wedding'

UPDATE #EntityValues1
SET @Values1 = Values1 =
        CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 
            THEN FirstName
            ELSE @Values1 + ' and ' + FirstName 
        END
```

However this example only works with combining FirstName1 + FirstName2 + LastName (in a subsequent query with *MAX(Values1) + ' ' + LastName*.  I had to do a subsequent query to take the approach where I am combining names that do not have the same last name.  I know this particular query is a bit tricky, but I'm wondering if there's any magic I'm missing out on.  I've seen some suggestions that use a **FOR XML** approach with STUFF involved, and some other suggestions, but this one appears to be a tough one.

Comment: One question, what order do you want the names combined in, based on the data?

Comment: @Jodrell The order is relevant, but in my case, there's flexibility.  I figure there are the standard ordered by alpha ascending/descending per last names if not combined, first names if combined, etc.  But I have the flexibility for this solution to go with any given combination/ordering pattern with the first/last names names of the 2 combination possibilities for "wedding".  For now, I suppose ordering the final output by HouseID, EventType would serve a nice grouping purpose for visual observation.

Comment: To add, beyond HouseID and EventType, the order of names isn't significant.  So for your answer which nailed it, very well done.  Thank you for your input @Jodrell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer, with a [working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qzJS5dTQ)

```
;WITH
[DoubleWeddings] AS (
SELECT
            [HouseID]
    FROM
            @t
    WHERE
            [EventType] = 'Wedding'
    GROUP BY
            [HouseID],
            [EventDate]
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) = 2
),
[DoubleWeddingsSameLastName] AS (
SELECT
            T.[HouseID]
    FROM
            [DoubleWeddings] DW
        JOIN
            @t T
                ON T.[HouseID] = DW.[HouseID]
    GROUP BY
            T.[HouseID],
            T.[LastName]
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) = 2
),
[DoubleWeddingsDifferentLastName] AS (
SELECT [HouseID] FROM [DoubleWeddings]
EXCEPT
SELECT [HouseID] FROM [DoubleWeddingsSameLastName]
),
[Couples] AS ( 
SELECT
           T.[HouseID],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.[HouseID] ORDER BY 1/0) [RN],
           T.[FirstName],
           T.[LastName],
           T.[EventType],
           T.[EventDate]
    FROM
           [DoubleWeddings] DW
        JOIN
           @t T
               ON T.[HouseID] = DW.[HouseID]
)
SELECT
            DWSL.[HouseID],
            FORMATMESSAGE(
                '%s and %s %s',
                F.[FirstName],
                S.[FirstName],
                S.[LastName]) [FinalName],
            F.[EventType],
            F.[EventDate]
    FROM
            [DoubleWeddingsSameLastName] DWSL
        JOIN
            [Couples] F
                ON F.[HouseID] = DWSL.[HouseID] AND F.[RN] = 1
        JOIN
            [Couples] S
                ON S.[HouseID] = DWSL.[HouseID] AND S.[RN] = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT
            DWDL.[HouseID],
            FORMATMESSAGE(
                '%s %s and %s %s',
                F.[FirstName],
                F.[LastName],
                S.[FirstName],
                S.[LastName]) [FinalName],
            F.[EventType],
            F.[EventDate]
    FROM
            [DoubleWeddingsDifferentLastName] DWDL
        JOIN
            [Couples] F
                ON F.[HouseID] = DWDL.[HouseID] AND F.[RN] = 1
        JOIN
            [Couples] S
                ON S.[HouseID] = DWDL.[HouseID] AND S.[RN] = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT
            T.[HouseID],
            FORMATMESSAGE(
                '%s %s',
                T.[FirstName],
                T.[LastName]) [FinalName],
            T.[EventType],
            T.[EventDate]
    FROM
            @t T
        LEFT JOIN
            [DoubleWeddings] DW
                ON DW.[HouseID] = T.[HouseID]
    WHERE
            DW.[HouseID] IS NULL
    ORDER BY
            [HouseID],
            [EventDate],
            [FinalName]
```

There is one issue, I've used the `ORDER BY 1/0` technique to skip providing an order for the `ROW_NUMBER()` which tends to assign the row numbers in the order of the underlying data. However, this is not guaranteed, and could very depending on the parallelization of the query.

It would be better if the order of the combination was provided by a column in the data, however, none is present in the example.

Comment: Thank you for the insight and good point regarding the parallelization of the query.  In such a query that I would use, I would make sure to provide a column to order by per your recommendations.  :)

Comment: @Novatone The business rules behind the precedence of couple naming are beyond the scope of the code and I wanted to avoid any assumptions about gender or priority. These things can be fraught and inflammatory.

Comment: Agreed.  This was a spectacular job well done and helped me see real insight on how to envision the solution given the required rules.  Though, I agree with anyone who would say much of this should be in the Application layer, unfortunately due to paging, it forces some of this to exist in SQL which as we know, is often a bottleneck and not easily scalable.  Once again, thank you tremendously for your insight and expertise.

Answer (score 1):

To get this event calendar:

```sql
select 
  t.HouseID,
  CONCAT(STRING_AGG(CONCAT(FirstName,
                           ' ',
                           CASE WHEN ln.LastName<>t.LastName 
                                then t.LastName END),' and '),
         ' ',
         MIN(t.LastName)) as Name,
  t.EventType,
  t.EventDate
from t
left join (select t1.HouseID, min(t1.LastName) as LastName from t as t1 GROUP BY t1.HouseID having count(t1.LastName)=1) ln on ln.HouseID = t.HouseID
GROUP BY t.EventDate,  t.EventType, t.HouseID
order by month(t.EventDate), day(t.EventDate);
```

output:

| HouseID | Name | EventType | EventDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Will Stanton | Birthday | 1974-01-05 |
| 4 | Stephen and Janetsy Johnson | Wedding | 2012-01-30 |
| 8 | Jessica Bower | Birthday | 1996-02-26 |
| 6 | Sandy Katz | Wedding | 2010-03-19 |
| 3 | Mark and Stacy Mellony | Wedding | 2021-04-04 |
| 7 | Sandra Kirchbaum | Wedding | 2011-05-22 |
| 1 | Mary Stanton | Birthday | 1980-05-22 |
| 8 | Frank Fjorn | Birthday | 1969-07-19 |
| 6 | Jeff Trilov | Wedding | 2016-09-09 |
| 5 | George and Sally Jackson | Wedding | 2009-11-15 |
| 2 | Jason Stockmore | Birthday | 1987-12-07 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/4Jf5a1Eo)

EDIT:

- Corrected the columnname (`Name` to `FinalName`), and the ordering of the results.
- Fixed the value for HouseId=5

```sql
select 
  t.HouseID,
  CONCAT(STRING_AGG(CONCAT(FirstName,
                           ' ',
                           ISNULL(ln.LastName, t.LastName)
                                ),' and '),
         ' ',
         MIN(ln.LastName)) as FinalName,
  t.EventType,
  t.EventDate
from t
left join (select t1.HouseID, min(t1.LastName) as LastName from t as t1 GROUP BY t1.HouseID having count(t1.LastName)=1) ln on ln.HouseID = t.HouseID
GROUP BY t.EventDate,  t.EventType, t.HouseID
order by HouseID, EventDate
;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/XuokwFol)

output:

| HouseID | FinalName | EventType | EventDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Will Stanton | Birthday | 1974-01-05 |
| 1 | Mary Stanton | Birthday | 1980-05-22 |
| 2 | Jason Stockmore Stockmore | Birthday | 1987-12-07 |
| 3 | Mark Mellony and Stacy Mellony | Wedding | 2021-04-04 |
| 4 | Stephen Johnson and Janetsy Johnson | Wedding | 2012-01-30 |
| 5 | George Jackson and Sally Mistmoore | Wedding | 2009-11-15 |
| 6 | Sandy Katz | Wedding | 2010-03-19 |
| 6 | Jeff Trilov | Wedding | 2016-09-09 |
| 7 | Sandra Kirchbaum Kirchbaum | Wedding | 2011-05-22 |
| 8 | Frank Fjorn | Birthday | 1969-07-19 |
| 8 | Jessica Bower | Birthday | 1996-02-26 |

Comment: The `Name` column should be `FinalName`. The name value for `HouseID` `5` is wrong. The results are in the wrong order.

Comment: It was a good stab at it, but it didn't account for the scenario of the last names being different which is a requirement in this particular scenario.  @Jodrell pointed out #5 was indeed mismatched to the final result as it picked a single last name, but required a separate First/Last name combination.; part of what made it tricky.